# How do I get the current page using PagedDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I am using the Umbraco CMS and trying to make next and previous buttons to scroll through a collection of pages/nodes. I have managed to get the total number of pages to be correct but the CurrentPageIndex is always showing as 0, how do I get the CurrentPageIndex of where the page is in the list created by my PagedDataSource and increment/decrement it to move to the next page?

The code I have got so far is:

Asp.Net:

```
<div class="detail-paging">
<div class="list-paging-control">

    <p><asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="lnkFirstPage">&lt;&lt;</asp:HyperLink></p>

    <p><asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="lnkPrev" OnServerClick="lnkPrev_Click">&lt;</asp:HyperLink></p>

</div>
<div class="list-paging-numbers">

    <p><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCurrentScroll"></asp:Label></p>

</div>
<div class="list-paging-control left-marker">

    <p><asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="lnkNext" OnServerClick="lnkNext_Click">&gt;</asp:HyperLink></p>

    <p><asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="lnkLastPage">&gt;&gt;</asp:HyperLink></p>

</div>
<div class="list-paging-text">
    <p><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkViewAll" OnClick="ViewAll_Click">View All</asp:HyperLink></p>
</div>
```

C#:

```
    private PagedDataSource paging;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DoDataBind();
    }
}

public int PageNumber
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
            return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PageNumber"]);
        else
            return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["PageNumber"] = value;
    }
}

//ALL CODE THAT BINDS DATA FROM UMBRACO
public void DoDataBind()
{
    //Get the parent node.
    Node parent = new Node(1152);

    //Get all the BrandsDetailPage children and order alphabetically.
    IEnumerable<INode> nodes = HelperMethods.GetChildrenOfType(parent, "BrandsDetailPage", true, true).OrderBy(n => n.Name);

    //Pagination
    paging = new PagedDataSource()
    {
        AllowPaging = true,
        DataSource = nodes.ToList(),
        CurrentPageIndex = PageNumber,
        PageSize = 1
    };

    //pageNumber = paging.CurrentPageIndex;

    CreateNavigation();
}

//ALL CODE THAT BINDS DATA FROM UMBRACO

//PAGINATION
public void CreateNavigation()
{
    lblCurrentScroll.Text = PageNumber.ToString();
    lblCurrentScroll.Text += " of ";
    lblCurrentScroll.Text += paging.PageCount;
Node node = new Node(1153);
    string nodeUrl = node.Url;
    lnkViewAll.NavigateUrl = string.Format("{0}?page=All", nodeUrl);
}

protected void lnkPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PageNumber--;
    DoDataBind();
}

protected void lnkNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PageNumber++;
    DoDataBind();
}
```

Comment: you should get at the information that you need using something like this `dataSource.PageSize = pageSize;
    dataSource.CurrentPageIndex = pageNo ?? 0;` also why are you setting page size as 1..?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `<asp:ListView />` together with an `<asp:DataPager />`. This simplifies paging in most situations and can do a lot of thing "automatic". See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24065/Paging-ListView-With-DataPager) for a nice example.

I have used it a view times in my Umbraco projects with succes. There is also the possibility to override some standard functions of the Datapager, in case you need it.